# Cannot get z-index to work on positioned elements

Tags: css, z-index

I am trying to get an image that is in a ul to sit on top of the ul's border. The ul is positioned relative and the image is positioned absolute. I can not for the life of me figure out why the z-index is not working.

Here is my html:

```
<nav id="mainNav">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
   <img src="http://bluesquarestudio.ca/images/arrow.png">
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my css:

```
#mainNav{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainNav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid #01AEF0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
#mainNav li{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px; 
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height:25px;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainNav a{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 117px;
}
```

This is how I want it to look:
[image: This is how I want it to look]

This is how it does look:
JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eempey/vv19kopq/

Comment: why not move the border on to your `li`s http://jsfiddle.net/haxxxton/vv19kopq/1/

Comment: Yeah that works, but I'm trying to get the border to extend the whole width of the page. Otherwise the border would stop at the end of the list elements.

Comment: you could also then add an element set behind the entire `ul` that has a similar border width and style: http://jsfiddle.net/haxxxton/vv19kopq/2/

Comment: Yes! That's the ticket. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working, is that you have `overflow:hidden` on the `ul`, so everything that goes outside of its *padding* area is cut off – and that includes the part of your images that are over the *border* area of the `ul`.

So this is not a `z-index` issue at all. (See my fiddle, no `z-index` set *anywhere*.)

As soon as you remove `overflow:hidden`, it works as expected. (Of course only after applying another method to make the `ul` contain the floated `li`, f.e. by floating the `ul` as well or applying an `:after` clearfix.)

http://jsfiddle.net/vv19kopq/6/

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can't position a child element on top of its parent?

The solution to my problem is to create another element, instead of using the parent's border. See haxxxton's jsfiddle above.

Comment: You can't if the parent has a z-index.

Comment: @Aibrean: That’s simply not true.